# React native execution fails on sqlite because of async-storage

Tags: sqlite, react-native, asyncstorage

My app was working fine and still build-able but I haven't touched the code for weeks.
Yesterday I got this error and today I updated from `@react-native-community/async-storage` to `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` but still getting errors below:

```
Note: D:\..\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\asyncstorage\AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find sqlite-framework-2.1.0.aar (androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/sqlite/sqlite-framework/2.1.0/sqlite-framework-2.1.0.aar
   > Could not find sqlite-2.1.0.aar (androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/sqlite/sqlite/2.1.0/sqlite-2.1.0.aar
```

The mentioned files were unreachable from Google on 20 May, and today they are accessible but I'm stilling facing the same error.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Do you have any more insights? Was your problem solved?

Comment: Resetting the computer fixed it for me. Maybe stopping grade daemon`./gradlew --stop` fixes it too.

Comment: Maybe banning problems. Can't remember.